# IllegalStateException in MediaPlayer set datasource method

Tags: android

I'm using the following code in my `onCompletion` listener of `MediaPlayer` where I'm repeating the current song.

```
if (isRepeat) {
                if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                }
                try {
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.localTrackList.get(MainActivity.currentOffset).getPath());
                    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

But I'm getting the following error Message,

```
  at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
09-15 09:05:19.884 12545-12545/ W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1115)
09-15 09:05:19.884 12545-12545/ W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1100)
09-15 09:05:19.884 12545-12545/ W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1079)
09-15 09:05:19.884 12545-12545/ W/System.err:     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1028)
```

How can I be able to sort this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MediaPlayer.setDataSource()` is only useful when the `MediaPlayer`'s state is Idle, you called this method in `onCompletion` so the android system gave you a `IllStateException`. `mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()` seems always return false in `onCompletion` method.

Actually you do not need to `setDataSource` again, you can just call `MediaPlayer.start()` to play the data from start.

See this state diagram (taken from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram):

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If your MediaPlayer is not playing anything or track is over, it will not be reset. Take your `mMediaPlayer.reset();` out of if condition

```
try {
    mMediaPlayer.reset();
    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(MainActivity.localTrackList.get(MainActivity.currentOffset).getPath());
    mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You should call `reset()` before using `setDataSource()`.

Your condition is absolutely write if media is playing, but it went false when track is over.

Comment: prepareAsync is not working for me, whereas prepare is working. Can you explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Lets suppose you have a list of songs and on click of song you have to play the song from file. **You need to re initialize the MediaPlayer again**. Setting isLooping is optional

Here file path is from internal dir "/system/media/audio/alarms/Osmium.ogg

```
fun onItemClick(item: FetchMedia.SongModel) {
    if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(item.DATA);
    mediaPlayer.prepare();
    mediaPlayer.start();
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
}
```